# arg_max summarize Timegenerated

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

Hi all I need to filter a query for application name found in the latest timegenrated

```
| project ComputerName_s, AppName_s, AppVersion_s, TimeGenerated
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ComputerName_s, AppName_s
| where ComputerName_s == "xxxxxx" and AppName_s in ('Google Chrome')
```

I use this but i have result of 12/1/2023 Timegenerated, but the last one is 12/4/2023 and the application Chrome doesn't exists anymore on that machine
How can I check only for the latest timegenerated about that machine?
Thanks

```
| project ComputerName_s, AppName_s, AppVersion_s, TimeGenerated
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ComputerName_s, AppName_s
| where ComputerName_s == "xxxxxx" and AppName_s in ('Google Chrome')
```

Answer (score 0):

The above query will give latest date when the `AppName_s` is in `('Google Chrome')`. It won't give the last date(latest date) of the table if that is not `'Google Chrome'`.

> but the last one is 12/4/2023 and the application Chrome doesn't exists anymore on that machine How can I check only for the latest timegenerated about that machine?

You can use below query to get the latest `Timegenerated` for a particular `ComputerName_s` irrespective of the `AppName_s`.

```
let a= datatable (Id:int, ComputerName_s:string,AppName_s:string,AppVersion_s:int,TimeGenerated:datetime)
[
    1,"Dell","Google Chrome",2,datetime(8/1/2023),
    2,'Dell','Google Chrome',3,datetime(8/3/2023),
    3,'Dell','Edge',4,datetime(8/9/2023),
    4,'HP','Google Chrome',5,datetime(8/9/2023),
    5,'HP','Google Chrome',6,datetime('8/23/2023'),
    6,'Lenovo','Google Chrome',7,datetime(10/10/2023),
    7,'Lenovo','Edge',8,datetime('8/5/2023'),
    8,'Lenovo','Firefox',9,datetime(12/12/2023)
];
a
| where ComputerName_s == 'Lenovo'
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated,*)
| project ComputerName_s, AppName_s, AppVersion_s,TimeGenerated;
```

[image]